# how to require constants which is exported in ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The original variables are exported in ES6 module like this:

```
export const url = 'https://example.com/api'
```

I know I can use this variable using
`import {url} from 'src/api'`

But the thing is I can't use `import` in `gatsby-config.js` file and only can use ES5 syntax.

I tried like this:

```
const {url} = require('src/api')
```

but it doesn't work and get errors while `gatsby develop`

The error is following:

```
export const url = 'https://example.com/api'
  ^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  - v8-compile-cache.js:226 NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:226:18

  - v8-compile-cache.js:172 Module._compile
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:172:36

  - loader.js:995 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10

  - loader.js:815 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32

  - loader.js:727 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14

  - loader.js:852 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - gatsby-config.js:4 Object.<anonymous>
    C:/project/gatsby-config.js:4:26

  - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30

  - loader.js:995 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10

  - loader.js:815 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32

  - loader.js:727 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14

  - loader.js:852 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - get-config-file.js:33 getConfigFile
    [project]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/get-config-file.js:33:20
```

Comment: Use `module.exports` instead?

Comment: Use something like [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) before loading - that's your only choice if it must be an ES6 module imported in a CommonJS module?

Answer (score 1):

When you exporting your constant if you use `module.exports` it should not give this error. Do it like this:

```js
const yourUrl = 'https://example.com/api'

module.exports = { url: yourUrl }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you know what you are trying to achieve because the result produces anti pattern against gatsbyjs specification as it already converts code internally from `es6` to `es5` after reading and validating `gatsby-config.js`.

So, try this way to require constants in `gatsby-config.js` which were exported in es6 module

- From `es6` to `es5` conversion, install `@babel/cli` and `@babel/core` package i.e `npm install @babel/cli @babel/core --save-dev`
- Add new npm/yarn script in package.json -> scripts -> `"prepare_config" : "NODE_ENV=test babel ./gatsby-config.js  <LIST_OF_FILES_TO_CONVERT>  --out-dir ./"`
- Make sure `babel-preset-gatsby` directory is present under `node_modules` if not then install it i.e. `npm install babel-preset-gatsby --save-dev`
- Either add `.babelrc` in project root directory having below code for babel preset and conversion.

> ```
> {
>     "presets": [
>         [
>             "babel-preset-gatsby",
>             {
>                 "forceAllTransforms": true,
>                 "useBuiltIns": "usage"
>             }
>         ]
>     ]
> }
> ```

- OR if you don't want to add .babelrc then specify babel configuration in package.json.

  ```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "babel-preset-gatsby",
        {
          "forceAllTransforms": true,
          "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
  ```
- Now run `npm run prepare_config` script first for conversion which will import required constants which were exported in ES6 module.
- Then you can run `gatsby develop` successfully.

Answer (score -2):

Change the `type:"module"` or set in `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo "Error: notestspecified" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Export const  that is module type so change the package json type: module